# How does grounding prevent electric shock?

Tags: grounding

I understand that an electrical appliance will be connected to ground to provide a path back if there is a fault and a live wire touches the case.

However if a person is also touching the case at this point then surely there will be a current through both paths? Because a person is like a parallel resistor to the ground connection. The current won't be as great, but it will be enough to be dangerous.

Do we just hope that the breaker will blow quick enough to prevent the shock happening for too long?

Comment: Why would the current choose to flow through the human touching Earth??  ….short answer it would not, therefore the human is not exposed to a high voltage.

Comment: If the case is (properly) grounded then it's at ground potential! So no voltage across the person, and zero current through the person.

Comment: Its not the circuit breaker but the RCD will trip and save you. If exists.

Comment: Here is one of the best explanations in the youtube, Go through the link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOdJmDaarbk

Comment: @Giga-Byte the link to youtube video should really be the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the impedance of the live and the ground return path are roughly identical, a person touching the case during the ground fault will face half the live voltage. That's already much better than full live voltage. You could provide a thick ground return path to drop this voltage even lower.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0I5J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But yes, the protective effect comes from the fuse on the live wire blowing due to the short circuit.

Comment: Wrong!!! The resistance to Earth is important, but to get a shock a human would have to provide a better path to Earth.

Comment: No, Jack. The current takes *all pathes*, not only that one with lowest impedance.

Comment: You are correct, BUT the human is ONLY touching the Earth (the outside Earthed case of the appliance), and the amount of current that would need to flow to raise that Earth wire to a dangerous voltage is huge. Now if the human managed to get BETWEEN Live and Earth the story is different

Comment: No, the human isn't touching earth but a case. Given the live and the ground wires are identical, and connected at the case due to the fault, that means the case is at half of the live voltage. It's a simple voltage divider.

Comment: In addition to grounding the case, to improve safety electrical codes call for the use of Ground Fault Circuit Interrupters (GFCIs) in outlets in kitchens or bathrooms (where there is water involved, what makes a shock potentially more lethal). The idea is that the circuit is interrupted if there is a small imbalance between the live and the neutral currents going to the appliance, what is an indication that current is going somewhere where is not supposed to. In the case of a live wire touching the case directly, the hope is that the GFCI will trip much earlier than the main circuit breaker.

Comment: Not so I'm afraid. The voltage is dropped across the breaker. If it's  a short, then most of the voltage is dropped across the magnetic portion of the breaker ...but this is also in series with the thermal actuator. But just to examine your statement ….if the ground wire was at a maximum permissible resistance, say a 12AWG 20A circuit ...the resistance is 1.6 Ohm/kft. Think of a normal housed circuit where cable lengths are rarely beyond 200ft ...so about 0.32 Ohms per leg. To develop half the mains voltage across this would requires about 180A. Very unlikely.

Comment: @joribama Great point, in those circumstance the GFCI breaker will trigger in just a few mS and they present a quite appreciable inductance which slows the transient short circuit current.

Comment: @JackCreasey - in addition, in real life you expect a wire to case short to take effect gradually, starting by the wire barely touching the case. In this case the GCFI should trip before the short becomes really dangerous.

Comment: @Janka Explain to me how you would measure your 'half the mains voltage??  The appliance is connected to a wall socket. The appliance metal case connected to the Earth wire. The Live wire has just shorted to the Earth wire ….what would the human connect to to get a shock ...there is no other path. The human would have to be connected to another Earth wire that was NOT carrying the fault current to be exposed. I can conceive of no circumstances where this could occur for a consumer using an appliance.

Comment: @Jack: Picking up a live kettle with one hand with the other in the kitchen sink. Earthing has been around a lot  longer than GFCI/RCDs.

Comment: @Transistor I don't deny that ...but the simplistic 'half the mains voltage' presented is far from the truth. Even if you project back to the good old days of fuses, the amount of power required to melt the fuse was enormous. For a fuse to blow at say 4x it's rating it had to drop almost 50% of the line voltage for almost 100ms. So the voltage at the fault point has dropped drastically. In todays mag/thermal circuit breakers the voltage dropped is much higher (due to the inductance of the mage element. At fault conditions the mag is likely to drop 70% or more of the line voltage at 4x current.

Comment: I've made a schematic.

Comment: @Jack Creasey: The fuse is irrelevant for the voltage. What's important is the impedance of the ground wire. And that one is just the same as the impedance of the live wire in households. – In commercial setups, mounting frames have their own, thick ground return paths. This is mainly for ensuring the fuse will blow, but it also lowers the ground impedance, and thus, the voltage which may be on the case under fault conditions.

Comment: The fuse (or circuit breaker) is of course relevant, it takes considerable power to flip the breaker or melt a fuse. That means dropping voltage across the device. However you seem not to understand that so I'll drop it there.

Comment: We are talking about the very moment before the fuse kicks in. That was the question.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of circuit-breakers and grounded cases is to remove any *long persisting* situations where the metal case was already dangerous when a human touched it.

If you pick up an ancient all-metal electric drill with a 2-prong cord, where the Line conductor has *contacted the metal case weeks ago*, nothing will happen  ...until you step into a pool of water in the basement, or lean on a steel kitchen sink, or grab a metal conduit for balance, etc.   Now your body is unexpectedly connected between Line and earth/neutral.

But still you aren't in serious danger, since you'll probably yell *YOW!!!* and yank your hand away from the earthed surface, or perhaps drop the drill, breaking the circuit.

For less lucky people, the lethal danger is from "clamp on," where the current through your body causes your muscles to push harder onto the electrically-live metal case or grounded object.   With the above power-drill, when stepping into a saltwater pool, your hand may grip it hard, and your arm-muscles also freeze, so you cannot shake it free.  (For lucky people, their arm muscles contract, violently flinging the power-drill across the room!)  During clamp-on, the current may interfere with breathing, so, if you cannot fall to the floor in order to pull loose, you'll slowly die of suffocation.   If the path is through your chest, the current may interfere with heartbeat (either immediately for a weak heart, or, since the heart is quite shielded by surrounding tissues, much time may be required before skin conductivity increases at the contact points, the fault current increases, and eventually your heart cannot beat normally.)

Search for electrocution and "clamp on."

The OP question is about a live-enclosure fault which happens while the user is both touching the case, and also is securely connected to Earth (e.g. grasping a faucet with the other hand, etc.,) and ALSO, either the current-path is across the chest and ALSO they have a serious heart condition where a half-second 120VAC shock is lethal rather than just surprising   ...THAT, OR they encounter "clamp-on" and suffocate over ten minutes of constant shocking.

Obviously the grounded case and blown breaker removes the last danger.

Heart-attacks caused by brief encounters with 120VAC during the time before the breaker blows: they remain a (rare) instance which could be avoided by that special device sold in the 1970s which detects tens of microamps of ground current, and then "blows the breaker" within a half-cycle of 60Hz, using active electronics.

***That 2-prongs world of our ancestors:***
  [thirty electrocutions thirty](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bre/sets/72157611077138836/) (from 1930?)